# Table in Latex -- How to make perfect column lines?

Tags: tables

The code blow is related to a table. However, the column lines are discontinuous and I need perfect lines from top to bottom. How to do that?

```
\begin{table*}[t!]
    \caption{Table} 
    \label{tab:tbl2}
    \centering % center the table
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c c | c} 
    \toprule 
    {} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{a}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{b}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    {c}  & d  & e & f  & g \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{h}  
    & \multirow{2}{*}{i}        
    & j
    & \multirow{2}{*}{k}
    \\
    {} & {} & f & {} & h
    \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{l} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{m}        
    & n
    & 
    &  
    \\
    & {} & b & $ c 
    \\ 
    & {} & d & f 
    \\
    & & f & &
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: You are using `\(top|mid|bottom)rule` from the `booktabs` package. However the documentation says "Never, ever use vertical rules." If you do want vertical rules you have to use `\hline` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that on this website, many (most?) recommendations aimed at making your table look attractive will focus on *NOT* using vertical lines at all. They're not needed! Really! Put differently, a "perfect" table neither requires nor benefits from vertical lines. In addition, you'll find many recommendations here to use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

I, for one, certainly subscribe to these views. In addition to following the recommendations given in the preceding paragraph, I would also eliminate the whitespace padding to the left of the  first column and to the right of the final column, and I wouldn't use right-hand trimming on the second `\cmidrule`. And, I'd replace the lone `\hline` directive with `\midrule`.

The following screenshot shows a before-and-after comparison. The table on the left is based on your code, while the one on the right implements the suggestions made above. (To make the tables look less abstract, I tripled all letters.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Before} 
    \label{tab:before}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c c | c} 
    \toprule 
    {} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{aaa}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{bbb}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    {ccc}  & ddd  & eee & fff  & ggg \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{hhh}  
    & \multirow{2}{*}{iii}        
    & jjj
    & \multirow{2}{*}{kkk}
    \\
    {} & {} & fff & {} & hhh
    \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{lll} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{mmm}        
    & nnn
    & 
    &  
    \\
    & {} & bbb & $ccc$ 
    \\ 
    & {} & ddd & fff 
    \\
    & & fff & &
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{After} 
    \label{tab:after}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{5}{c} @{}} 
    \toprule 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{aaa} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{bbb}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    {ccc}  & ddd  & eee & fff  & ggg \\
    \midrule% not "\hline"
    \multirow{2}{*}{hhh} & \multirow{2}{*}{iii} & jjj & \multirow{2}{*}{kkk} \\
    & & fff & & hhh \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{lll} & \multirow{4}{*}{mmm} & nnn \\
    & & bbb & $ccc$ \\ 
    & & ddd & fff \\
    & & fff \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed the mentioned advice.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

`MWE:`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{table*}[t!]
    \caption{Table} 
    \label{tab:tbl2}
    \centering % center the table
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
    \hline 
    {}      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{a}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{b}                 \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    {c}     & d                                     & e                     &   f   & g     \\  \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{h}                              & \multirow{2}{*}{i}    &   j   & \multirow{2}{*}{k}    \\
    {}      & {}                                    & f                     &   {}  & h     \\  \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{l}                              & \multirow{4}{*}{m}    &   n   & {}    \\
     {}     & {}                                    & b                     &   \$  & c     \\ 
     {}     & {}                                    & d                     &   f   & {}    \\
     {}     & {}                                    & f                     &   {}  & {}    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I agree that vertical lines in tables should be avoided, please explain how your MWE solves the OP's request: " I need perfect lines from top to bottom".

Comment: @leandriis-- That is why the question mark at the end of the first comment--OP needs to comment whether it satisfies HIM? Restructuring the table per my perspective may kindly be allowed. There are of course a variety of combinations which can be placed. Learning from your answers at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496691/197451

Comment: @leandriis The perfect lines are there, just invisible :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want vertically rules compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` (even though this is *not at all* in the spirit of `booktabs`), you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
    \caption{Before} 
    \label{tab:before}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c | c | c c | c} 
    \toprule 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{aaa}  & \Block{1-2}{bbb}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    ccc  & ddd  & eee & fff  & ggg \\
    \hline
    \Block{2-1}{hhh}  
    & \Block{2-1}{iii}        
    & jjj
    & \Block{2-1}{kkk}
    \\
    & & fff & & hhh
    \\
    \midrule
    \Block{4-1}{lll} 
    & \Block{4-1}{mmm}        
    & nnn
    & 
    &  
    \\
    & & bbb & $ccc$ 
    \\ 
    & & ddd & fff 
    \\
    & & fff & &
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]